# How to retrieve an object with filtered children through JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I have a specific problem I can't seem to find an answer to. I'm currently working in a Java Spring MVC environment, using Hibernate JPA.

In this situation, simplified, you could say I have following hierarchy:

```
Form entity with
@OneToMany
List<Page> pages;

Page entity with
@OneToMany
List<Question> questions;

Question entity with
String status;
```

Some of these questions have a status of either *PRODUCTION* or *ARCHIVED*. Simple enough, right?

Now, what I want to do is: I want to create a JPA query, that will allow me to retrieve the Form object, but containing only those Question objects that have a status as *PRODUCTION*.

So when I execute the query, I have a Form object, containing pages with questions. All the questions are questions that are in production, no archived ones.

How would I go about to do this?

EDIT: I mistakenly set a @OneToMany relation on my above example, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When you prepare your question model then you can add:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private String status;
```

then your entity

```
Form entity with
@OneToMany
List<Page> pages;

Page entity with
@OneToMany
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

Question entity with
@OneToMany
String status;
```

And jpa;

```
@Override
    public List<Form> getFormsByStatus(String status) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Form f where f.status = ?1")
                .setParameter(1,status);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate you can use `@Where` on your association.

There is very little write on the subject here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection